# Error with Quicktime when loading movie with c# 2005

Tags: .net, quicktime

I have a program that will play videos ".mov" from a queue.  If there are no videos in the queue then the "attract loop" video reloads.  I am using the event handler "qtEventMovieDidEnd" that fires when the movie ends.  This event handler when fired asks if there are any movies in the queue and if not it reloads the attract loop file and is supposed to play it.  My problem is that when the event fires at the end of the movie it tries to reload the file and throws an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll".  I can remove the event handler and manually load any movie by using a button click event and load it that way, it works perfect when I do that.  The error sends Visual Studio .net 2005 to my "program.cs" file and exits.  It stops at "Application.Run(new Form1()).
Why does the event handler throw an error but when I manually load a movie it works great?
The methods in my code:

```
private void addMovieEventListeners(QTMovie myMovie)
{
    // Make sure a movie is loaded first
    if (myMovie == null)return;
    myMovie.EventListeners.Add(QTOLibrary.QTEventClassesEnum.qtEventClassStateChange,
        QTEventIDsEnum.qtEventMovieDidEnd, null, null);
}

public void PlayMovie(string movie)
{
    axQTControl1.URL = movie;
    addMovieEventListeners(axQTControl1.Movie);
    axQTControl1.Movie.Play(1.0);
    frm1.lblMoviePlaying.Text = axQTControl1.Movie.URL;
}

private void axQTControl1_QTEvent(object sender, _IQTControlEvents_QTEventEvent e)
{
    if (e.eventID == (int)QTEventIDsEnum.qtEventMovieDidEnd)
    {
        axQTControl1.Movie.EventListeners.RemoveAll();
        //MessageBox.Show("Movie Ended");
        PlayMovie(@"C:\AttractLoop\AttractLoop.mov");
    }
}
```

Comment: You didnt post the contents of `qtEventMovieDidEnd` - please post that if you want assistance.

Comment: The axQTControl1_QTEvent is fired when the movie ends and I searched the eventID with that method for a 'qtMovieDidEnd' event.  The event does fire and the message box does show.  I found out that if I leave the message box on the screen then I don't get a system error, but when I click the 'OK' on the message box the system error pops up.  I have been researching this and I'm reading a lot about memory leak issues, I'm not sure if that is my problem or not.

Comment: It still would be helpful to have that method displayed, since your code snippet doesnt talk about MessageBox's at all.

Comment: I ended up scrapping the idea of using "qtEventMovieDidEnd" and just used the length of the movie subtracted by the playhead time position.  Once the time was less than 500ms I loaded the attract loop again.  It has been working with no bugs.